# How to check if the key exist in json array?

Tags: javascript

I have a json object, the structure of which is given below. I try to find if the key (for eg: `1` & `2`) exist or not by myArray.includes(`'1'`) but it doesn't work. Is looping through the array the only way to check if attribute exist or not?

```
[{"1": [{}]},{"2": [{}]}]
```

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to create an answer and they aren't searchable for future readers. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 3):

The way to check if an object with a particular property exists or not would be to filter the objects by verifying if they have given property or not.

To check if an object contains a property you could use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on the list of keys obtained through `Object.keys`. Here's an example:

```js
var data = [
  {"1" : []},
  {"2" : []}
];

// Count of objects containing a given key.
console.log(data.filter(t => Object.keys(t).includes("1")).length);
console.log(data.filter(t => Object.keys(t).includes("2")).length);
console.log(data.filter(t => Object.keys(t).includes("3")).length);
```

Comment: This is what I want. But how about `excludes`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through all of the elements in the Array and check if the key exists in each of those Objects.

```
arr.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('1'));
```

Comment: Also possible to check `1 in e` - it's shorter but it also checks the entire prototype chain. If that's undesirable, then `.hasOwnProperty` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a `boolean` indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

```js
let arr = [{
  "1":[{}],
  "2":[{}]
}]
let checkOne = arr.some(x => x.hasOwnProperty('1'));
let checkThree = arr.some(x => x.hasOwnProperty('3'));

console.log(checkOne) //true
console.log(checkThree) //false
```

Comment: If there is an key with [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, this won't work. Eg: `{"1": 0 }`

Comment: @adiga yes I just thought of that. Thanks for information. Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test.

```
const has1 = myArray.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(“1”)); // Returns a boolean
const has2 = myArray.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(“2”)); // Returns a boolean
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try forEach to loop the keys of object and check if yours is there.

```
var obj = yourobject;

var mykey = 0;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    if(k == mykey){
    ...
}

});
```